# How to make work Restfull /user/register?_format=hal_json

Tags: 8

I am trying to access. All required modules are included, rights granted. so does not work.
*/user/register?_format=hal_json*

I get a message:

```
{"message":"Not acceptable format: hal_json"}
```

In RestUi settings, hal_json format is enabled.

And in the log:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotAcceptableHttpException: Not acceptable format: hal_json in Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\RenderArrayNonHtmlSubscriber->onRespond() (line 30 of .../web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/RenderArrayNonHtmlSubscriber.php).
```

Drupal 9.0 and Drupal 8.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add at header:

```
 Content-Type : application/hal+json
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check, maybe JSON data from the frontend doesn't cover inside of `JSON.stringify(...)` and you try to send regular data which not serialized for sending?

I advice to make sure you stringify data before sending:

`const data = {"some":"value"} JSON.stringify(data)`